# File, Unnamed Pipe, Named Pipe and Socket

Tags: file, sockets, pipe

If we are provided with File, Unnamed Pipe, Named Pipe and Socket. What are the scenarios in one is preferred over other and why apart from the obvious cases from the definition(wrote down my understanding below) ?

**File :** traditionally, persistent data on the file system

**Unnamed Pipe :** Temporary data channel for interprocess communication, 2 unidirectional end points for read and write

**Named Pipe :** Used same as unnamed pipe, but not dependent on the life of the process

**Socket :** Have bi-directional end points, generally used for communicating over the network.

Comment: This looks like homework given without useful context. While we could help with such question it is expected that the OP does its own research first (and shows it) and also provides sufficient context to actually make the question answerable.

Comment: It is not a homework but was asked in one interview.

Comment: Named pipes can also be used for communications over the network.

Comment: @Anjani: thanks for editing the question. It is better now but I still find that it is missing context. For example the context might be general local or remote inter-process communication or more specialized different ways to provide a password to another process or something else. Even if such context was not explicitly provided, the kind of interview you had might provide the context, i.e. interview for some general junior programmer job, for a programmer in the field of system security, for a consultant who should teach others secure programming etc.

Comment: remy-lebeau Thanks for adding to the list
@SteffenUllrich  It was an open ended question. The role was data engineer for junior level in a **startup**, thereby expecting varied knowledge. Despite the role, I would like to strengthen my knowledge apart from the definition, hence the question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau As both of named pipe and socket is used for communicating over the network, could you please help with when one is preferred over the other ?